# Do the Peaky Blinders speak Shelta or Romani to the Lees?

Tags: dialogue, peaky-blinders

I'm aware that the actors playing the Peaky Blinders speak badly translated Romanian, but my question is what language they are meant to be speaking. Are they and the Lees Travelers, and therefore speaking Shelta? Or are they and the Lees Romani, and therefore speaking a Romani language?

My instinct is that the answer is 'Romani' because of articles like this one [here](http://entertainment.ie/tv/news/Cillian-Murphy-lived-with-gypsies-to-prepare-for-new-drama-Peaky-Blinders/211674.htm#).

But then I see articles like this one [here](https://www.travellerstimes.org.uk/features/blinding-bit-telly) that muddy the waters a bit by seeming to claim the Shelbys are Travelers...although, we should note, this article blurs the line between Romani and Travelers, which makes me wonder whether the whole basis for my question is confused...

Comment: From your Travelers source: "Tommy is a character whose Romany ethnicity is acknowledged by the author as fact [...] there’s the odd bit of Romany language"

Comment: Good point @OrangeDog but note these other semi-confusing lines from that article: "interestingly, things calm down a bit when Tommy ends up being related to the Lees by marriage, which may not tally exactly with some Travellers’ actual experience" and "like any Traveller, hearing these terms makes my blood boil..."